# Getters / Setters / Assigning one object to another

Tags: iphone, xcode, setter, getter

I have a class called Chair.

I have a view controller that contains an object of type Chair.

At some point, I am trying to assign my viewcontrollers instance to another instance of a Chair object as such:

```
[viewcontroller setChair: thisChair];
```

My setter looks as such:

```
- (void) setChair:(Chair *)thisEntryChair;
{
        myVCChair = thisEntryChair; 
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
[setChair:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

whether I use a setter function or plainly as such or use a setter:

```
viewcontroller.myVCChair = thisEntryChair;
```

This approach, if I have done it in the same manner as I have other variables which I believe I have, I assume is having issues as this is a custom object not an inbuilt one?

Help!

Comment: Do you use any @property or synthesize?

Comment: The object is a @property in my .h and is @synthesize in the .m.  

And apologies (Re: answer) , I am using something like aChair vs Chair

e.g.
viewcontroller.aChair= thisEntryChair;

Comment: Please see updated post above that corrects this mistake in posting originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think the class name and the field name being the same might be a problem.  Try renaming your member variable `aChair` or something to see if it works.  Then you can choose a name you like better.</s>

UPDATE BASED ON QUESTION EDIT:

@synthesize shouldn't be used if you want your own setter.  The setter should be named

```
 -(void) setmyVCChair: (Chair*) aChair {
     myVCChair = aChair;
 }
```

Then you can use `viewcontroller.myVCChair = anotherChair`

Comment: I am performing it like this, and yet it continues to crash :(

I am performing it in the EXACT same manner that I do it to an NSURL contained in the same class.

This is why I figured it might be something odd with custom objects being used vs inbuilt NSURL etc

Answer (score 0):

so in your example the code would be:

```
[viewcontroller setChair:somechair];
```

or

```
viewcontroller.chair = someChair;
```

The internal class ivar myVCChair isn't exposed.

Comment: arg, I'm sorry!! 

When I posted this question I made a few mistakes in trying to generalise my code...  

Please see edited version.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your answer sorry.  What do you mean by the internal class ivar myVCChair isn't exposed?

I have declared it as a property and synthesize and hence it is exposed?

Apologies, I am not yet up to speed on all the lingo